# Python different behaviour with abstractmethod

Tags: python, abstract-class, abc

I have two classes inheriting from the same parent `P`:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class P(object):

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod  
    def foo(self):
        pass

class C(P):
    pass

class D(tuple, P):
    pass
```

The only difference is that `D` inherited from `tuple` and `P` while `C` inherits from `P` only.

Now this is the behavior: `c = C()` got error, as expected:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class C with abstract methods foo
```

but `d = D()` works without error!

I can even call `d.foo()`. How can I explain this behaviour?

Comment: FYI, with Python 3 they both instantiate just fine.

Comment: Is that capital case Class working for you? Are you not getting any syntax error?

Comment: @Keith is that preferred? why doesn't `abstractmethod` work?

Comment: @Keith: that's because in Python 3 you need to adjust the metaclass syntax; `class P(metaclass=ABCMeta):`. Once you do so you'll see the same issue on Python 3, `C()` throws an exception, `D()` does not.

Answer (score 8):

Abstract methods are tested for in the `object.__new__` method; when you inherit from `tuple`, which has its own `__new__` method, `object.__new__` is not called and the test for abstract methods is not made.

In other words, mixing abstract methods with *any* of the built-in immutable types will cause this problem.

The only solution that works is to do your *own* test in `__new__` and then only if you put your abstract class *before* `tuple` when mixing in the two bases in a subclass.

```
class P(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super_new = super(P, cls).__new__
        if super_new.__self__ is not object:
            # immutable mix-in used, test for abstract methods
            if getattr(cls, '__abstractmethods__'):
                raise TypeError(
                    "Can't instantiate abstract class %s "
                    "with abstract methods %s" % (
                        cls.__name__,
                        ', '.join(sorted(cls.__abstractmethods__))))

        return super_new(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    @abstractmethod  
    def foo(self):
        pass

class D(P, tuple):
    pass
```

Comment: Man, you're a legend :)